# Finding the number of elements in a json object

Tags: javascript, json, iteration, javascript-objects

I can't figure out how to find the number of elements contained in a JSON object with JavaScript. This is how my object is structured:

```
var shows = [];
//make http call here to api url and store in variable called 'data'
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var element = {
    "location": {
      "latitude": data[j].venue.latitude,
      "longitude": data[j].venue.longitude
    },
    "artist": data[j].artists[0].name,
    "venue_name": data[j].venue.name,
    "date": data[j].datetime
  };
  shows.push(element);
};
```

So I can access the elements easily by using `shows[i].location` or whatever key I'd like access. However, all the question/answers that cover this topic seem to recommend `Object.keys(shows).length` to find the number of elements (I've also had trouble getting a for-each loop to work for this object of elements).

However, this doesn't work in my case (I'm assuming because 'shows' doesn't have any direct keys) so I was just wondering if there is any other way to access the number of elements (each with 4 key : value pairs) that are inside of "shows"? Or is there just another way to iterate over every element? Or if that is not possible is there another way I could structure my object to make it easier to find the number of elements? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property? `shows.length` which, incidentally, is equal to `data.length`. Side note: that's not a "json object." JSON is a textual format which can be converted into data. What you have there is an array of objects.

Comment: `This is how my object is structed` - so, it's an array of objects ... the length of the array would be data.length

Comment: I'm expecting there's some code missing, because you're using `int i = 0` (which isn't even valid JavaScript), but then referencing `data[j]`, which would cause an error.

Comment: I really messed this question up I'm going to link this to a new question that actually makes sense hopefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

> [A]ny other way to access the number of elements (each with 4 key : value pairs) that are inside of "shows".

The "number of elements" you are speaking of is the length of the array that you are pushing objects onto.  The objects pushed each have four key-value pairs.

You would determine the number of elements (length of the array) using (or in an array):

```
var lengthOfShows = shows.length;
for (var i = 0; i < shows.length; i++) {
  var currentShow = shows[i];
  // references
  // shows[i].location
}
```

In your code ...

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
```

Should be ...

```
for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
```

Since you are referencing data[j] inside the for-loop.

Comment: That makes sense thank you. Sorry the question was so confusing, I was mixing up my java/javascript and should have pasted my code directly. But for some reason shows.length is returning zero while shows[0].artist returns a real string (so that means there are more than 0 elements I'm assuming). I don't know if this is a scope issue because I am filling the object in a separate function and then calling the shows.length in a different one? But then I can call shows[0].artist correctly so this confuses me (also data.length is not the same bc I have an if statement that filters some of the data)

Comment: Check the for loop you are using to populate the array; you are using `i` in the code above and `j` inside the loop ... this could give odd results.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, `shows` is an array. Arrays have a length property.
    `shows.length`

is probably what you need.  Looks like it would be the same as `data.length` and
that data is probably also an array.